# Constant string being erased after using strncat()

Tags: c, cs50

so i wrote this for cs50s substitution problem

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // check CLI argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const string KEY = argv[1];
    bool key_validity = true;
    char unique[] = ""; // check for unique lettered key

    // iterate through each letter and check if not letter
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(KEY); i++)
    {
        int ascii = (int) toupper(KEY[i]);
        if (!(ascii <= 90 && ascii >= 65))
        {
            key_validity = false;
        }

    // nested for loop. iterate each letter n see if it present in array
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(unique); j++)
        {
            // compare each letter of unique to ascii, then add ascii letter to unique
            if ((int) unique[j] == ascii)
            {
                key_validity = false;
            }
        }
        strncat(unique, &KEY[i], 1);

        printf("%c\n", KEY[i]);
        printf("%s %s\n", KEY, unique);
    }
```

I expected it to add the characters from KEY one by one to unique, while KEY remains constant but on executing ./substitution bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza the output is this

```
b
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza b

 bc
```

so it means b and c is being added to unique, then KEY is being erased somehow. Im pretty sure the culprit is the strncat() line because commenting it out makes the program behave normally. please help me out

Comment: Please break yourself of the habit of using magic numbers like `65` and `90` in your code when comparing strings. You can just use character literals like `'A'` and `'Z'` instead.

Comment: Also, if you include `<ctype.h>` you have functions `isupper` and `islower`.

Comment: `strncat(unique, &KEY[i], 1);` This will write 2 bytes to `unique` which can only holde 1 byte. You need extra space for the terminating 0 byte. BTW: For copying 1 character, you can just assign that single character without calling that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, your `unique` string is exactly one character long: just long enough to hold the null terminator, but no actual content.

To alleviate this, you need to specify that `unique` is longer, though you can still initialize it with `""`.

For instance, making it able to hold `1024` bytes.

```
char unique[1024] = "";
```

You should also note that after determining `key_validity` you never use that variable.

You also likely don't mean to print the original string `KEY` and the unique key on each iteration.

Correcting a lot of your issues, and eliminating the CS50 stuff (as I do not have that header).

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check CLI argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const char *KEY = argv[1];

    // Since C99 supports variable length arrays, use that to
    // make unique as long as it needs to be.
    char unique[strlen(KEY) + 1];

    // Count of characters in unique.
    size_t j = 0;

    // Iterate through each letter.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(KEY); i++)
    {
        char current_char = KEY[i];

        // go to the next iteration immediately if we're not looking at a letter.
        if (!isupper(current_char) && !islower(current_char)) 
            continue;

        // Check if the current_char is in unique already.
        bool already_present = false;
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(unique); i++)
            if (current_char == unique[i]) {
                already_present = true;
                break;
            }

        if (!already_present)
            // Add the current character and increment the count of letters in unique.
            unique[j++] = current_char;
    }

    // Null terminate unique.
    unique[j] = 0;

    printf("%s %s\n", KEY, unique);
}
```